# Atom Editor italicizes the word REVIEW and colors it blue - How to Disable?

Tags: atom-editor

Atom Editor italicizes the word REVIEW and colors it blue. Why? My text format is selected as "plain text". There shouldn't be any syntax formatting. How do I disable this?

It only happens when the letters are all caps like this `REVIEW`. Is this related to the monokai theme? When in "plain text" mode all other words and characters are white on a black background. Just this one word is goofy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by a plugin that highlights to-do items, e.g. [the Todo Show Package](https://atom.io/packages/todo-show).

I have this installed, and I see the same behavior as you, when typing `REVIEW` or `TODO` in a text file:

[image: Todo Example]

The Todo Show package's settings allow you to specify which words to highlight, and as you can see, the default value includes `REVIEW`:

[image: Todo Show Settings]

If you want, you can overwrite this setting and omit the `REVIEW` word if the highlighting really bothers you.

Please check if you have this package installed or a similar one. I'm pretty sure that the highlighting is caused by one of these.